# jquery/xml2json - Uncaught Error: XML Parser could not be instantiated

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-plugins

I tried tu use xml2json plugin by testing the simple exemple and I had exception in Chrome:

Uncaught Error: XML Parser could not be instantiated

```
var xml = '<xml><message>Hello world</message></xml>'; 
var json = $.xml2json(xml); 
alert(json.message);
```

Comment: did you include jQuery library to your page? if yes, it needs to be on top of your xml2json file.

Comment: Yes, jquery is include to the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to double check the compatibility of the xml2json plugin and jquery. I just ran into this issue and resolved it by updating the xml2json plugin. It also depends on which xml2json plugin you are using. We are using the following:

- [xml-to-json by Fyneworks](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/) v1.3
- jQuery v 2.0.3

We saw the problem when we upgraded jQuery from 1.9.1 to 2.0.3 but did not upgrade the xml2json plugin (we were at 1.2). If you look at the [Source Diff](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-xml2json-plugin/source/diff?path=/trunk/jquery.xml2json.js&format=side&r=27) you will notice that there is a block of code that is commented out with a description of "prior to jquery 1.9".

There are other xml2json plugins that we haven't tried, so I can't comment on them. I hope this helps!